# External/USB controller integrated with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, midi

I own an APC MINI USB/MIDI button pad and have been trying to get windows to more or less recognize it as a operating-system-wide input device. My primary use case is to trigger macros or shortcuts in Eclipse.

For example, instead of the current keybinding of ALT+] to clone a window I could press [btn_1] on the external controller to trigger the action. Another example is I could move the slider up and down changing the zoom on my text.

Ideally I'll be able to fire off any macro or shortcut just by pressing a button on the USB pad. If I could get it working at the OS level, I could see having a row of buttons start or focus frequently used applications. For example be able to open FireFox or press a button to navigate a tab to StackOverflow.com.

I supposed I COULD slap together a quick jar with a Midi library, listen for input from the device and map the "notes" (button presses) to a key combination/shortcut but I feel like there has got to be a way to have windows treat the pad as an input device just like a mouse or keyboard. Been all over the internet looking for solutions but most use cases deal with software engineered to handle midi input. Not afraid to write .bat files to cooperate with windows but still need some way to link the buttons on my board to said .bat files.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How should Windows know how to map MIDI messages to keys? You have to run your own program that calls [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput), and I doubt that Java is capable of that.

Comment: Take a look at something like Glove PIE.